# why is this not finding my shared object file in eclipse cdt (using intel mkl)?

Tags: eclipse-cdt, intel-mkl

I'm testing the Intel MKL using Eclipse and I get my code to compile just fine.

```
12:31:41 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project YKP_C ****
make all 
make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.

12:31:41 Build Finished (took 85ms)
```

However, I keep getting an error message

`/home/ypitcan/workspace/YKP_C/Debug/YKP_C: error while loading shared libraries: libmkl_intel_lp64.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

when I try to run the code.

[image]

This is my configuration, which looks right according to the instructions online.

[image]

Please I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Your *compilation/linking* phase is working fine from the screenshots shared.

What is failing is the *running*. You need to tell the program, when you run it, where to find `libmkl_intel_lp64.so`.

To do that, normally you set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable which works sort of like `PATH` but for finding `.so` files.